# How are foreign militaries regulated in the USA?

Tags: military, usa, regulations

I believe the US military is not officially subject to the FARs, but what about foreign military aviation?  What about aviation activities of the various National Guard outfits?

Example...the Belgium air force operating a squadron of C-130's during a training exercise held in the USA.

Comment: Yes, foreign military operating in US airspace and utilizing US civilian airfields.

Comment: Example...the Belgium air force operating a squadron of C-130's during a training exercise held in the USA.  My first time, apologies for the missteps.

Comment: I belive all aircraft operating in civilian airspace (military included) must at least have proper equipment aboard and follow civilian regulations on airspace etc. Even US military planes cary civilian transponders and radios for this reason. They can however operate without those things with prior approval.

Comment: The overall issue we are faced with is whether or not foreign military aviation activity in the USA is considered "General Aviation" or "Military" by the FAA.  Figured stipulations on whether or not they must comply with the FARs would be definitive.  Same issue with Air National Guard aviation activity.

Comment: As to flight rules(different than aircraft and pilot certifications) US military aircraft are very much subject to all the same rules as civilian aircraft. They just bother with the paperwork to get special permissions for stuff like block altitudes for convoy flights. For fancy combat practice flying they must stay inside an posted-active restricted area or warning area.(which is generally still monitored and controlled by civilian ATC)